# Encountering problems encoding characters

Tags: python, regex, list, utf-8

I'm retrieving long lists of songs `ids` from `API`'s, and I'm appending them to a list:

```
track_ids = [spotify:id:1,spotify:id:2 ...]
```

latetr on, song values are being passed to a function, in order to get corresponding song names, in this fashion:

```
(...)
for i, x in enumerate(values):
        if x > threshold:
            track_name = sp.track(track_ids[i])['name']
            xsongs.append(track_name)
            print product.upper(),'-', "{} = {}".format(track_name, x), filter_name
```

But when I run the script the list of song names output is halted showing the following error:

`print product.upper(),'-', "{} = {}".format(track_name, x), filter_name
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 7: ordinal not in range(128)`

**EDIT**:

the following line fixed it:

```
xsongs.append(track_name.encode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: What code is actually triggering the error? Usually, this sort of problem occurs when you try to do something with a `unicode` object that only takes strings, so it tries to encode them to `str` using a "safe" encoding (one that can definitely be represented by your computer; unfortunately, that means ASCII only. Explicit encoding sometimes works, or using Unicode friendly libs that don't need to convert to `str` (or use Py3, which is much more Unicode friendly overall).

Comment: The `results` is list or string? If it is a list, you should encode single element. If it is a string, you can transform it to list, then decode element.

Comment: @EmL it is a list. how do I do that? care to answer?

Comment: @ShadowRanger I get this: `songs = [value.decode('utf-8') for value in sample_songs]
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 7: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: What are you printing *to*??  You've completely changed the meaning of your question with the edit. If Python is choosing to encode with `ascii` during a print, then your terminal is misconfigured or you are printing to something besides a terminal that requires more help to decide properly. Manual encoding is usually not the answer.

Comment: @Mark Tolonen sorry, I was trying to avoid too much code posting only the core of the matter, but it seemed that the problem was in a module being imported. I'm very sorry to have misguided you, but encoding the variables rooted deep inside the module seemed to have fixed the problem I had tackled only at the surface. sorry again.

Comment: @data_garden: You've got your calls backwards. Calling `decode` on a `unicode` object is almost always wrong (which is why it's not even a method of Py3 `str`). Calling `decode` on a `unicode` object implicitly _`encode`s_ with the default codec here (ASCII on your system) before decoding. Change the listcomp to call `value.encode('utf-8')` and it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can encode every element of list. If your file system encoding is `utf-8`, you can try:

```
results = [value.encode('utf-8') for value in results]
print(results)
```

Comment: I still get this: `songs = [value.decode('utf-8') for value in sample_songs] File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework‌​/Versions/2.‌​7/lib/python‌​2.7/encodings‌​7;utf_8.py", line 16, in decode return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True) UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 7: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: Add `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` to your py file header.

Comment: @EmL `coding` line does nothing except declare encoding of the source file.  It doesn't help encoding or decoding strings at run time.

Comment: @MarkTolonen yes, you are right.
@data_garden The original value is unicode, you should use `value.encode('utf-8')`

Comment: @EmL I accepted your answer because I fixed the code using your idea.

Answer (score 0):

The strings in your example are already decoded since they are Unicode strings.  You can't decode a Unicode string again, so Python 2 implicitly encodes it back to a byte string using the `ascii` codec, hence the "Unicode**Encode**Error".  The strings you have are correct, you are just seeing escape codes for the non-ASCII characters, which is the default when printing a list.  Print the individual strings instead:

```
results = [u'Magic Carpet Ride', u'La Grange', u'Tausendmal ber\xfchrt',
           u'Funkelperlenaugen',u'Lied F\xfcr All Die Vergessenen']

for r in results:
    print r
```

Output:

```
Magic Carpet Ride
La Grange
Tausendmal berührt
Funkelperlenaugen
Lied Für All Die Vergessenen
```

Comment: problem persists. please refer to question EDIT.